# PHP url rewriting CSS not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, web, url-rewriting

I am working on a PHP application , which generates the following link

`http://localhost/24_2_april/video-library/2/Programming-Language`

but ever since i have used htaccess to make my URL clean , since then the CSS and JS are not working . Now i know i could give the absolute path for the cSS , but i don't think that would be the right approach , also i tried using `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` , but no luck so far ....

This is my htaccess code so far.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^video-library/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ var/www/html/24_2_april/video.php?cat_id=$1&category=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^video-library/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ var/www/html/24_2_april/search_results.php?cat_id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: What is the path of your CSS and JS files?

Comment: it's inside my project folder only.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the way to go is using RewriteCond. These rewrite rules will only be executed if there is no actual file available. If your files are symlinks you may need to add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}% !-l`

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}% !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}% !-d
RewriteRule ^video-library/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ var/www/html/24_2_april/video.php?cat_id=$1&category=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}% !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}% !-d
RewriteRule ^video-library/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ var/www/html/24_2_april/search_results.php?cat_id=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^video-library/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ http://localhost/24_2_april/video.php?cat_id=$1&category=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^video-library/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ http://localhost/24_2_april/search_results.php?cat_id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: sorry brother , but that didn't work out . The page is just loading up without the CSS and the JS.

Comment: now the CSS is working , but the rewriting is not done properly.

Comment: Update htaccess to RewriteBase /24_2_april/ and then remove full URL from rule. e.g /search_result.php, /video.php

Comment: Tried it . It gave an `Internal Server Error`